# Get value from multidimensional collection

Tags: laravel, collections, laravel-5.4

Let's say we have :

```
$collection;
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#312
  #items: array:20 [
    "id" => 1
    "externals" => {#314
      +"anothertypeofid": 2
      +"evenAnother": 3
      +"foobar": 4
      }
    ]
   }
```

Is there a way to get foobar without checking if it exists in the collection. and just return null if it does not.

```
// you got.
$collection->get('id');   // Will return null if it does not exists.

//  But you cannot do 
$collection->get('externals.foobar');
```

What would be the fastest way to accomplish this ?

Update :

In the end I want to return a new array

```
return [

  'anothertypeid' : value of collection>externals>anothertypeofid or null,
  'namedDifferently': value of collection>externals>foobar or null
]
```

So I was thinking something like this.

```
return [
'anothertypeid' => $collect->pluck('anothertypeofid')->filter()->first(),// must return null if it does not exists in collection.
...
]
```

Also I could convert the collection to an Array and use helper **array_get()**

```
return [
   'anothertypeid' => array_get($array,'externals.anothertypeofid',null); 
// will return null if not found
   ...
]
```

is there a cleaner and/or more efficient way to do this ?

Comment: why can't you convert it to array and then get foobar

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? $collection->get('id') will return object with key equal to the string 'id' if it exists in the collection, not the value of id field. Do you want to get `foobar` value of all items in the collection?

Comment: Thanks for answering.  It will contain only a single "id"  with a multidimensional collection.  In the end I want to return a new array [ with a couple of those externals id's.  But they might not exist.  So I wanted to see if there is a nice way to clean up the code. I updated the code.